# Datamapper ORM / Codeigniter - - - validate relation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

i have the following DB:

---

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE likes
(
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id BIGINT,
idea_id BIGINT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ideas
(
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

---

user model:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Relationships
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

public $has_many = array( 'like' , 'idea' , 'comment' );

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Validation
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

var $validation = array(
    'username' => array(
        'label' => 'Username',
        'rules' => array('required', 'trim', 'unique', 'min_length' => 3 )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'label' => 'Password',
        'rules' => array('required', 'trim', 'min_length' => 3 ,'encrypt' )
    )
);
```

---

idea model:

```
public $has_one = array('user');

public $has_many = array('like');

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Validation
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

public $validation = array(
    'user' => array(
        'rules' => array('required')
    )
);
```

---

like model:

```
// Relationships
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

public $has_one = array( 'user' , 'idea' );

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// Validation
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

var $validation = array(
    'user' => array(
        'rules' => array('required', 'unique_pair' => 'idea' )
    ),
    'idea' => array(
        'rules' => array('required')
    )
);
```

---

like controller

```
    $idea = new Idea(1);

    $user = new User(1);

    $like = new Like(); 

    if( !$like->save( array( $idea , $user ) ) )
    {
          echo $like->error->all;
    }
    else
    {
      echo "ok";    
    }
```

---

The problem is that i always get OK and the likes are saved in the database and does not get validated.

what i want is to get both fields ( user_id , idea_id ) unique

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$model` and `$table` properties in the models, this support the relations. After, verify your `foreign keys`. Remember the singular for model name and plural for table name.

```
public $model = 'user';
public $table = 'users';

....
public function __construct($id = NULL) {
    parent::__construct($id);
}
```